Angular Signals: programming semaphore
I want to run an action just once when a condition changes (to true), e.g.
areAllDetailsLoaded() => run a function

I was thinking to code it as a Signal like
areAllDetailsLoaded=signal(false);

and using it as
effect( () =>  {
   if (areAllDetailsLoaded()) {
          storage().getDetails() ....... run code

The problem I'm facing is that obviously the Signal storage is also taken into account and anytime the storage() changes the code runs. Which is not something I want. After areAllDetailsLoaded is changed to true the code should run only once.
Honestly I'm running out of ideas. Or perhaps my understanding of Angular Signals is not good enough. Therefore a boiler template pattern would be appreciated - perfered with Signals.

I found some very nice observations.

Only the signal reads at the top level are triggering the effect, not sure if it's by design.

The effect returns a reference, with a destroy property to destroy the effect and make sure the signal runs only once.


Full code:
import { Component, effect, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button (click)="areAllDetailsLoaded.set(true)">areAllDetailsLoaded set true</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  areAllDetailsLoaded = signal(false);
  storage = signal(false);
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor() {
    const effectRef = effect(() => {
      console.log('effect runs');
      // const storage1 = this.storage(); // un comment this to see the effect running for each change of storage
      if (this.areAllDetailsLoaded()) {
        const storage = this.storage();
        console.log('code runs');
        effectRef?.destroy();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.storage.set(!this.storage());
      console.log('interval', this.storage());
    }, 1000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

That's a very nice approach and very nice pattern. Thx - this saves my day :-)

Here are two approaches to achieving what you want:

Using a private flag with ngOnChanges lifecycle hook

Using a BehaviorSubject from RxJS


